# Specialized template function vs specialized template function without template keyword

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

code1:

```
template<typename T>
T sum(T t1, T t2)
{
    return t1 + t2;
}

int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b + a;
}

int main()
{
    sum(10,20);
    return 0;
}
```

code2:

```
template<typename T>
T sum(T t1, T t2)
{
    return t1 + t2;
}

template<>
int sum<int>(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b + a;
}

int main()
{
    sum(10,20);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any difference in the specialized sum functions in both cases?
My compiler gives same output for both cases.
I always followed the first method. Is the difference only that from the second method we understand that it is a specialized function on the first look?

Comment: The first is an overload. The second is a specialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is template specialization, the second is function overloading. It matters in resolution rules - overload which matches exactly will be picked over specialized template.

Answer (score 0):

If you will have function sum2:

```
template<typename T>
T sum2(T t1, T t2)
{
    ...
    return sum<T>(t1, t2);
}
```

It would not call overloaded variant 1, but would call template specialization from variant 2.